# Index in my list that's looped through by a for-loop is out of bounds. It must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, indexing

Below is a code snippet of my `ShowForm()` method, which is used with my winforms.

```
public void ShowForm()
{
    hmf.ShowDialog();

    if (hmf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

        MessageBox.Show("DialogResultOK was hit.");
        // store winforms values into global vars

        try
        {
            Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String param = (Grasshopper.Kernel.Parameters.Param_String)Params.Input[0];
            param.PersistentData.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
            }
            param.ExpireSolution(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error message
        }
    }
    else if (hmf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DialogResultCancel was hit.");
        this.ExpireSolution(false);
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving.

[image]

I know that the `if` statement is hit, because my `DialogResultOK was hit` shows up. I am thinking the `for-loop` is somehow indexing out, but I'm not quite sure why it is doing so.

Comment: What is `Params.Input`?

Comment: It is a object from the Grasshopper class.

Comment: Are you completely sure this collection is not empty?

Comment: Let me check real quick.

Comment: It appears it's not: http://puu.sh/6urBk/f3838332c2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Params.Input` collection is empty. Thus trying to get item at index `0` gives you out of range exception.

Comment: Let me check real quick.

Comment: Wow. It seems every attempt at using `MessageBox.Show(Params.Input[0].ToString()) ` crashes my program every single time with no fail. I've tried it twice.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - You can set breakpoints to pause execution of your program at any point and inspect variables and other expressions, instead of displaying a message box. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: Hey Steve. I am currently working on a class library actually, so there really isn't any commandline output unfortunately.. The program executes onto a Grasshopper canvas, and the only way to debug it is through using `try-catch` statements and printing them through `Messageboxes`.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage you can use `Debugger.Break();` to break execution of application which uses your library. Also you can write `MessageBox.Show(Params.Input.Count().ToString())` to check real quickly whether collection is empyt

Comment: It was indeed empty. It was actually never called or used! Using `MessageBox.Show(..)` crashed my entire program as a matter of fact! Out of curiosity, how does `Debugger.Break()` help debug? Since I am currently working with class libraries, there are unfortunately no console outputs, which is why I must rely on `MessageBox..` to debug. My program "runs" when I use it on the Grasshopper canvas, so I can only debug on run-time outside of VS.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage `Debugger.Break()` stops code execution and launches debugger (you may require to attach debugger). That is useful when you cannot just run your code on F5 in visual studio (e.g. you are developing library which is used by service)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x.Count - 1; i++)
{
    param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
}
```

The main issue is that you are comparing `i <= x.Count` which is not a fixed number. Since `x.Count` is reevaluated during every iteration it's very possible for the index to end up out of the range of the count causing problems.

Instead you should set the for length before hand:

```
int count = x.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
}
```

The second issue is that `x.Count` is returning the number of elements in the array, if there are no elements, you end up with a count of zero. Well - an array with no elements cannot be accessed by the index, as there is nothing at index 0.

So, you skip the loop entirely if there are 0 items:

```
int count = x.Count;

if (count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        param.PersistentData.Append(new GH_String(x[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: `x.Count` should remain the same every time, but I agree with your assessment. Thanks for the code revision suggestions :-).

Comment: Can't understand - is it joke or not? Do you really use your last sample code instead of simple `for` loops? First - if you are changing collection size in a loop, then it's much better to evaluate collection size before each iteration, than saving some irrelevant collection size which it has before loop. Checking collection size before iteration guarantees you will not have index out of range on current iteration. Second - `for` loop checks condition before starting iteration. If you don't have items in collection, then `0 < x.Count - 1` will be false and you'll skip loop entirely.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy So it's a bad idea to use the `if(count > 0)..` code snippet?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage of course. `for` your loop is equivalent to `int i = 0; while (i < x.Count - 1) { ... i++; }` Do you need some additional checks here?

Comment: Should I still declare `int count = x.Count` beforehand, or should I just leave what I had be?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage leave as is, I explained in my first comment here why you should not do that

Comment: Thanks Sergey.. I'm still debugging that issue with `Params.Index[0]`, but once I figure it out I'll mark your answer. Thanks for all the help.